# How to create a new div dynamically everytime a element in data is introduced

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, pubnub, c3.js

I have a data coming from a VM that has several block devices. Every block device is represented with a a line charts that where created using c3.js that read Bytes_Read and Bytes_Written in the dataset and chart it in realtime. But I am struggling with the issue when there are new block devices introduced in dataset it does not create a new chart. What would be the best way to achieve this using JavaScript.

Sample of my dataset

```
    {
        "devices": [
            {
                "Name": "bdev0",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 0,
                    "Bytes_Read": 0,
                    "Bytes_Written": 0
                }
            },
{
                "Name": "bdev0",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 1,
                    "Bytes_Read": 2,
                    "Bytes_Written": 3
                }
            },
{
                "Name": "bdev0",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 5,
                    "Bytes_Read": 7,
                    "Bytes_Written": 8
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "bdev1",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 10,
                    "Bytes_Read": 20,
                    "Bytes_Written": 30
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Updated dataset with a new device

```
    {
        "devices": [
            {
                "Name": "bdev0",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 0,
                    "Bytes_Read": 0,
                    "Bytes_Written": 0
                }
            },
{
                "Name": "bdev0",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 1,
                    "Bytes_Read": 2,
                    "Bytes_Written": 3
                }
            },
{
                "Name": "bdev0",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 5,
                    "Bytes_Read": 7,
                    "Bytes_Written": 8
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "bdev1",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 10,
                    "Bytes_Read": 20,
                    "Bytes_Written": 30
                },
{
                "Name": "bdev2",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 40,
                    "Bytes_Read": 50,
                    "Bytes_Written": 90
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

chart code

```
eon.chart({
    pubnub   : pubnub,
    history  : false,
    channel  : 'orbit5_volume',
    flow     : true,
    debug: true,
    generate : {
        bindto : '#chart',
        size: {
        height: 180,
        width: 500
    },
        data   : {
            x      : 'x',
            labels : true
        },
        axis : {
            x : {
                type : 'timeseries',
                tick : {
                    format : '%H:%M:%S'
                },
                zoom: {
                   enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },

    transform : function(m) {
        for (var i in m.devices){
           return { columns : [
            ['x', new Date().getTime()],
            ['Bytes Written', m.devices[i].output.Bytes_Read],
            ['Bytes Read', m.devices[i].output.Bytes_Written]
            ]
          }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan: I dont want to update the chart but update the page with a whole new chart when a new block device is introduced.

Comment: Then you can just remove the chart and create a new one and update the page right?

Comment: Are you wanting a completely unique chart per device or just another line on the same chart?

Comment: @CraigConover A completely unique chart per device also I dont want to remove the previous charts that is if there is a new device in the data it just adds to the already existing charts

Comment: Have you been able to manually hard code two instance of EON chart or even c3 chart without EON with success?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're chart code transform loop is overwriting every data's key which is why you're only getting a couple values. If you use the `i` variable to give each piece of data a new key, it'll show up on the chart.

Try this transform function:

```
eon.chart({
    transform : function(m) {

        var obj = {columns: [
          ['x', new Date().getTime()]
        ]};

        for (var i in m.devices) {
           obj.columns.push(['Bytes Read ' + i, m.devices[i].output.Bytes_Read]);
           obj.columns.push(['Bytes Written ' + i, m.devices[i].output.Bytes_Written]]);
          }
        }

        return obj;
    }
});
```

Comment: deluxe `transform()` ftw